# Casting an Object reference into its generic type

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have an `Object` which is really a generic with an unknown type parameter.  How do I cast it into the proper generic type?  For example, here's my generic:

```
Public Class MyGeneric(Of T)
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal withName As String)
        Name = withName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a As Object = New MyGeneric(Of String)("a")
    Dim b As Object = New MyGeneric(Of Integer)("b")
    PrintName(a)
    PrintName(b)
End Sub

Public Sub PrintName(ByVal forValue As Object)
    Dim itsType = forValue.GetType()

    If (itsType.IsGenericType() AndAlso itsType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(MyGeneric(Of ))) Then
        Debug.Print(DirectCast(forValue, MyGeneric(Of )).Name)
    End If
End Sub
```

Why does the first `MyGeneric(Of )` work for a "named type" argument to `GetType()` but the second `MyGeneric(Of )` doesn't work for a "named type" argument to `DirectCast()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using reflection, a more reasonable design could help you. What does `PrintName` actually do? It prints the name of something. And that something is supposed to have a name. So why not create an interface for that?

```
Public Interface IHasName
    Property Name As String
End Interface
```

... and let your generic class implement it ...

```
Public Class MyGeneric(Of T)
    Implements IHasName

    Public Property Name As String Implements IHasName.Name

    '...
End Class
```

Then you could do:

```
Public Sub PrintName(ByVal forValue As IHasName)
    Debug.Print(forValue.Name)
End Sub

Dim a = New MyGeneric(Of String)("a")
PrintName(a)
```

This is much cleaner than casting an object around if you can't even be sure that it's of the correct type. Now `PrintName` explicitly states that it needs something with a name and the compiler can check this. You don't have to rely on the programmer to only pass valid objects.